# Has there ever been a case where a country adopted the currency of another country with a smaller economy?

Tags: economy, currency, finance

Sometimes sovereign nations abandon their currencies (partially or fully) and adopt the currency of another state. For example, the currency of El Salvador was replaced by the United States dollar in 2001.

Has there ever been a case when a country with a larger economy was primarily using the currency of another country? In the above example Salvador's GDP is less than 1/500 of the American GDP.

Comment: Anglo-Saxon and Norman England continued to use the silver *denarius* as coinage long after the Roman Empire GDP hit zero. Does that count?

Comment: This question should distinguish between [Fiat money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat_money) and [Commodity money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodity_money). The paper money of today (**Fiat money**) is probably what is meant. Money based on silver/gold (**Commodity money**), such as Roman coins (which were still used after the Roman Empire no longer existed) and European currencies, [Latin Monetary Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Monetary_Union), until 1914 are really not comparable to **Fiat money**.

Comment: Kosovo also I believe. They don't have larger economies than the EU, though.

Comment: How does adopting the currency of another country equate to colonization? You need to do a lot more work in this question to justify the question title.

Comment: @curiousdannii I parse the title as saying that the currency was colonized which seems justified.

Comment: Tenino in America used a wood currency stamped with a monetary value as legal tender for a time during the depression and now again under corona/covid-19 it seems. After the depression collectors later bought the notes replacing them with real tender. Apparently this trick allowed them to remain solvent during the depression.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace The danger for the smaller country would probably be higher, since they would have to take over the responsibility of the previously issued currency of the larger country. The (unrealistic) sample Canada/US makes the impossiblities clear. A large agricultural country, merging with a smaller industrial country may be a realistic scenario. Not sure where treason comes into this question.

Answer (score 7):

[United States of America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA) used [Spanish dollar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_de_a_8) as the (sole) currency [until 1792](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coinage_Act_of_1792) - it even remained a legal tender [until 1857](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coinage_Act_of_1857).

EDIT: In 1820 (when the Spanish dollar was still a legal tender and widely used), US GDP was 12548 million dollars (in 1990 US dollars), Spain 12299 million dollars – and US grew very rapidly very soon since then, while Spain stagnated. Source: [Maddison, A.: Contours of the World Economy, 1–2030 AD](https://books.google.sk/books?id=a-JGGp2suQUC&dq=Maddison,%20A.:%20Contours%20of%20the%20World%20Economy,%201%E2%80%932030%20AD), Table A4.

Comment: The 8-reales might be realy a good example. It was also commonly used in Southeast Asia and China, but not as the sole currency. And, I have a Mexican coin from the XIX c that kept the same size and weight of the 8-reales in order to be exchangeable with it.

Comment: When did USA GDP exceed that of Spain (other than during the interruption of 1808 - 1813)? Further, *specie* currency doesn't count because it's value is inherent solely on the contained precious metal. It's usage is just as fungible barter.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens by Maddison, A.: Contours of the World Economy, 1–2030 AD, US GDP in 1820 (when the Spanish dollar was still a legal tender and widely used) was 12548 M$ (in 1990 dollars), Spain 12299 M$ - and US grew very rapidly since then, while Spain stagnated.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík: Earlier than I thought. That belongs in the answer, not just as a comment.

Comment: China had an depression which made the paper Yuan era's paper money worthless. Their recourse were the silver from Spanish South America so

Answer (score 7):

Since [Fiat money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat_money) (paper banknotes) are often based on the strength of an **economy** of the country that issued it, it is unlikly that a bigger economy would be able to use the currency of a smaller economy due the amount of currency being printed (in circulation).

The issuing country would avoid printing to much paper money, since they are a form **promissory notes** that at some point must be redeemed

- for a *fiat* currency: goods produced by that economy
- for a *specie* currency: gold/silver held by the central bank that issued such notes

So in general, it is **not** in the (economic) interest of one country to *colonize* another using **Fiat money**, since this could lead to destabilization of their economy.

Comment: Further, it's impossilble with *specie* currency because that's just fungible barter.

Comment: This answer and the comment above imply that all decisions on the subject are taken rationally.  That is obviously not true, though I don't have an example like OP asks for.

Comment: @RossMillikan During WWII, Germany issued **Reichskredit­kassenscheine** for usage outside of Germany, to avoid it's local currency (Reichsmark) being spreed outside the country. This is the exact **opposite** of *colonization* that the OP is asking for. Many other countries did the same, for the same **rational**, practical reasons.

Comment: "since they are promissory notes that at some point must be redeemed." -- Citation needed on the latter claim. Pounds sterling have been circulating unredeemed (and in increasing numbers) for over 300 years...

Comment: @Tiercelet No, a citation is not needed for this, just because a small portion of the notes have not been redeemed.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: the vast majority of notes have never been redeemed, and it is unclear what redemption even means when, for example, a UK pound doesn't buy you a pound of silver anymore.

Comment: @nomen With a **fiat** money, you must exchange the notion gold/silver with goods produced by your economy. With a balanced trade, this poses no problem. With a trade deficit (more is imported than exported) and the difference is paid in local **fiat** money, then the holder of that money must be able buy something with it. Otherwise it is just useless paper.

Comment: @nomen With a *specie* currency (gold/silver) this was no problem, since that currency could be used elsewhere.

Comment: @nomen By the 31st of May 2020, it is estimated that 5.1 % of the Deutsche Mark was **not** exchanged for Euros (Source: Deutsche Bundesbank). So 94.9% was redeemed. So the statement *the vast majority of notes have never been redeemed* is not very realistic.

Comment: debased specie may affect adoption; if country X has more pure specie it will be preferred to country Y debased currency.  That _might_ be a case where a country would adopt external currency (Spanish dollars may approximate this case). (hat tip to @MarkJohnson)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace For *specie*, this is called **debasement**. This is what happened 1866, during during the [Latin Monetary Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Monetary_Union), when the Papal Treasury debased it's silver coins.

Comment: @MarkJohnson You are correct; the relationship between devalue and debase is interesting but only partially relevant to this question. I've made the correction.

Comment: @MarkJohnson typically the 'good' you can buy with fiat money is satisfaction of the taxation burden. E.g. USD which explicitly state on their face that they're the (sole) medium which can be used to pay US taxes. Very many people need to convert real-economy resources into dollars to pay that tax burden, thus the fiat currency is never useless paper so long as taxes are sufficiently high and unavoidable. And Euro conversion is a highly unusual--actually redeeming a currency like that was a remarkable event in modern times requiring years of planning... not something routine and inevitable.

Comment: @Tiercelet The USD is not a typical fiat currency. It's envolvment from full [gold standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_standard#Depression_and_World_War_II) (until 30 January 1934), partial gold standard (without domestic convertibility) and reserve currency (Bretton Woods, 1944) until August 1971, where international convertibility ended. Since October 1976 it is officially became a fiat currency, but due the role of reserve currency is nevertheless *atypical* of a normal fiat currency.

Comment: @Tiercelet If the USD was abandoned as a [major reserve currency (presently 61%)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserve_currency#United_States_dollar), it would cause serious problems for the US economy. It's capability to take on hugh depts would be severely hampered and problems in financing it's  trade deficit would occur. Production outsourcing of the past would then start to revenge itself, since production is a core element of a stable fiat currency. So at present, one should **not** assume that the USD is a typical fiat currency.

Comment: @Tiercelet How much do you think a country, such as Germany (with around USD 60 Trillion reserves), must pay in taxes to the US government? The definition on how papermoney can be used (to pay taxes) should not be mixed with how a fiat currency works.

Comment: @MarkJohnson USD has a unique reserve role due to having been the only developed economy standing after WWII, but the principle is the same for AUD, CAD, EUR, GBP, Yen... In any event: what do you mean in your answer by "redeemed" (vs. merely traded with other non-government actors) when fiat currency has no inherent convertibility to any other form of value, and how can you justify saying this "must" happen when there are notes worth 70 billion GBP in circulation (hence not redeemed) today and that number has been increasing steadily for over three hundred years?

Comment: @Tiercelet There is bo need to repeat my comments as to why tge USD is a **atypical** Fiat currency (and therefore should **not** be taken as a sample how Fiat currencies work). You are nixing grapefruits with oranges here. My answer pertains only to oranges.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Again--this answer seems to be relying on the premise that fiat currency is a promissory note that 'must be redeemed'. If 'redeemed' has the natural meaning of 'exchanged with the issuer for something other than more paper money,' this is both inaccurate (fiat issuers do not, and do not promise to, exchange currency for any real goods) and unnecessary to the answer--it's enough to say that a country that issues its own money (fiat *or* specie) has more control over its economy than one which doesn't (peg, currency union, etc), so why give up the power?

Answer (score -2):

Argentina is the classic case of a country that does not trust its own currency. Traditionally, Argentina suffers from inflation, so the US dollar is the refuge for most people. Actually, during the [decade of 1990](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_history_of_Argentina#Economic_crisis_(1998_-_2002)), Argentine currency was fixed to the dollar. So, during that time, Argentinians actually used their currency or dollars.

I still remember those years when Argentinians who traveled outside their country were surprised that in other countries did not accept their currency with the exchange 1 to 1 towards the dollar. They were offered far less than that.

Obviously, that fixed exchange was impossible to sustain, and ended in the crisis of [2001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998%E2%80%932002_Argentine_great_depression).

In fact, nowadays, there are [four times more dollars](https://www.infobae.com/economia/2020/03/15/los-argentinos-tienen-usd-130000-millones-en-el-pais-mas-de-4-veces-el-valor-de-todos-los-pesos-que-circulan-en-la-economia/) (link in Spanish) in Argentina's economy than its own currency (pesos). The amount of dollars per capita in Argentina is the highest in the world outside the USA. The exchange is fixed by the government, but in the black market you can buy dollars (called blue dollars) by paying double. In fact, newspapers show both exchanges ([check upper left corner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_history_of_Argentina#Economic_crisis_(1998_-_2002))).

So, even though Argentina still has its own currency, their own people try to not use it and buy dollars instead. But, since dollars are scarce in an economy where everyone wants dollars, the government sets a limit of dollars that each person can buy (200).

Comment: When has Argentina used the currency of a country with smaller GDP as its own legal tender?

Comment: Venezuelans also informally use the US dollar due to hyperinflation, but again, that's a way larger economy than their own and it's not state-sanctioned (but allowed by the state).

Comment: If they were asking for a 1:1 exchange wouldn't that actually indicate extreme confidence in their currency?